# Adonis.js populate all with related tables data

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js, adonis.js

I use MySql, all relationships have been configured correctly in models and schemas:

I have 3 tables:
1. posts ( main ) 
2. categories ( 1 post has 1 cat, 1 cat belongs to many posts )
3. tags ( many-to-many )

Categories and tags both have "post_id" column relating to "id" column in posts table.

What is the best way to get all related data ( post data + post category data + post tags data ) ? 
( for now I know I can get something like:

```
const post = await Post.find(params.id)
const category = await post.categories().fetch()
etc for every related table
```

I'm sure there must be better way.

I'd like result to be:

{
 *post data - name, text ...*,

"category": {
   *category data - name, text ...*
  },

"tags": [
   {
     *tag1 data*
   },
   {
     *tag2 data*
   }

]
}

Answer (score 1):

```
 const wantedData = await Post.query().where('id', params.id).with('categories').with('tags').fetch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to do this.

The Latest Adonis js Have the feature of the Query builder. You can perform almost all SQL queries using this. For Example

**#select**

```
Database
  .from('users')
  .select('id', 'username', 'email')
```

So There are many queries you can perform as your need. The following links will be very useful for you. [Query builder Documentation](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/database/query-builder#select)